# "Active" box on navigation bar not showing for dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

My problem is that for my navigation bar, it's supposed to have a green "active" box to show what tab the user is currently on. The box shows up for every tab I have, except for one, which happens to be a dropdown menu. Therefore, I need help figuring out why it doesn't appear. Is it because I declared 2 classes in an `<a>` tab? Here's my code: https://jsfiddle.net/wmzpktw7/. As you can see, there's no boxes on the "Games" menu. If you move `class="selected"` into another tab, you'll see the green box. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have two declarations for class inside the HTML element. Multiple classes can be declared like this:

```
<a class="dropbtn selected" href="#">Games</a>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mmd9u1h7/1/

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works now. So, does this mean that if I want more classes I can just add them in as well?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, you can add as many classes as you need in the same way. Just ensure that they are separated by a space.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and the answer